# Schedule email using wpMandrill to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, mandrill, schedule

Is that possible to schedule a message using wpMandrill plugin?

I saw in this [post](http://blog.mandrill.com/own-your-wordpress-email-with-mandrill.html) that we can use mandrill_payload filter to change anything in the structure (following Mandrill's API , [/messages/send](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send)).

How can I change the send_at parameter so that I can schedule e-mails to be sent.

Would it be something like this:

```
function customFilterSendAt($send_at)
{
  $send_at = "2016-01-23 14:00:00";
  return $send_at;
}

add_filter('mandrill_payload', 'customFilterSendAt');
```

Then

```
wp_mail($email_adress, $subj, $body );
```

?

Comment: You'll need to set up an actual cron job for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is possible to schedule emails using wpMandrill. This [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/schedule-emails-how-to) (check aaroneight comments) helped me.

To schedule your email using wpMandrill:

```
$message = array(
            'subject' => $subj,
            'from_name' => 'From Name',
            'from_email' => 'from_email@example.com',
            'to' => 'to_email@example.com',
            'html' => $body,
            'async' => false,
            'ip_pool' => null,
            'send_at' => '2016-02-24 19:45:00'
);


$sendmessage = wpMandrill::sendEmail($message);
```

Debugging:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($sendmessage,true).'</pre>';
```

Output example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => to_email@example.com
            [status] => scheduled
            [_id] => db835dfe43cd5d67b3743a30e184f84d
            [reject_reason] => 
        )
)
```

At this time, scheduled emails may only be managed via Mandrill's API, so you won't find them within Mandrill's Dashboard.

to list your scheduled emails you can use:

```
$url = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/list-scheduled.json';
$key = 'Your API key';
//$to = '';   // optional

$args = array(
    'body' => array(
        'key' => $key
    )
);

$results =  wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
$results = json_decode($results['body']);
```

Output example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 1d0xe54f3b759a1153b7a53g3321f4b6
            [created_at] => 2016-02-24 19:30:13
            [send_at] => 2016-02-24 19:42:00
            [from_email] => from_email@example.com
            [to] => to_email@example.com
            [subject] => Email Subject
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 1272e526f6924ba096d23146e2dxad4c
            [created_at] => 2016-02-24 19:31:12
            [send_at] => 2016-02-24 19:45:00
            [from_email] => from_email@example.com
            [to] => to_email@example.com
            [subject] => Email Subject
        )
)
```